# FLEX 4 Numeric Stepper value update problem?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, numericstepper

i have numeric stepper in MXML component.when i entered manually numeric value and press a button to add the current value in my datagrid column row.First time its not effected in datagrid column.But when i clicked second time value effected in my datagrird column.
How i can get manually entered value in datagrid column on first click of button.

Thanks Adavance!!!

protected function id_btnAdd_mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                {
                edlColor = new EDLColor();
                edlColor.ColorToString = "rgb(0,0,0)";
                edlColor.Extent = id_extent.value;
                elxFrame.ShapeStyle.ColorList.AddColor(edlColor);
                dispatchEvent(new ECContextChangeEvent(ECContextChangeEvent.CONTEXT_CHANGE, this, edlColor, ContextConstants.COLOR_CONTEXT));
                }
                //edlColor = new EDLColor();
                //colorList.AddColor(color);
            }

//This above function used to add value of numeric stepper in datagrid column

-->

```
        <mx:Spacer width="90%"/>
        <customclasses:IconButton id="id_btnAdd" name="{TDCommonConstants.IMAGE}"  
                                  skinClass="assets.skins.designer.IconButtonSkin"
                                  icon="{Icons.Add}" 
                                  mouseOverIcon="{Icons.Add}" 
                                  mouseDownIcon="{Icons.Add}"
                                  toolTip="{resourceManager.getString(TDCommonConstants.RESOURCE_LABELS,'ADD')}"
                                  mouseDown="id_btnAdd_mouseDownHandler(event)"
                                  height="12" width="10"/>

        <customclasses:IconButton id="id_btnRemove" name="{TDCommonConstants.IMAGE}"  
                                  skinClass="assets.skins.designer.IconButtonSkin"
                                  icon="{Icons.Remove}" 
                                  mouseOverIcon="{Icons.Remove}" 
                                  mouseDownIcon="{Icons.Remove}" 
                                  toolTip="{resourceManager.getString(TDCommonConstants.RESOURCE_LABELS,'REMOVE')}"
                                  mouseDown="id_btnRemove_mouseDownHandler(event)"
                                  height="12" width="10"/>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:HGroup height="90%" width="100%">
        <mx:DataGrid id="id_variableRefList" width="100%" height="95%">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn id="id_strip" sortable="false" > 
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="{data.UnsignedInt}" mouseDown="{outerDocument.hbox1_mouseDownHandler(event)}">
                            </mx:HBox>
                        </fx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>  
                </mx:DataGridColumn>
                <mx:DataGridColumn id="id_opacity" sortable="false"/>
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </s:HGroup> 
</s:VGroup>
```

Comment: sounds like a data binding issue.

Comment: Please provide a code for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add values to the dataGrid Column row?  Or to the DataGrid's dataProvider?  If you're updating the dataProvider, then the DataGrid won't necesarilly automatically update the itemRenderer, because the dataChange event won't fire automatically.  In your dataProvider is a collection class, you can use the [itemUpdated()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#itemUpdated%28%29) method.

```
dataProvider.itemUpdateD(myUpdatedItem);
```

Which will trigger the DataGrid to update.  You can also use the [refresh](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#refresh%28%29) method:

```
dataProvider.refresh();
```

But, considering the lack of code you provided, I'm just guessing.